# Angular firebase push notifications link not working

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification

I have an Angular app with a firebase Service worker to receive cloud messages from Firebase Cloud Messaging. My problem is when the notification is in background and I click it, the notification send me to my app at the specific route just when the app is closed runnnig in background, when the app is not focused it just open the app and no redirect to the route I passing.

I pass it to the fcmOptions (Code below, I´m using firebase admin to send notifications through nodejs server). I read a lot of documentation of how to redirect in web push notifications and migrate to the firebase admin after using the fcm API but it still working as I mentioned also in production.

Does anyone know how to solve this or could help me to redirect manually when the users click the notification using the notificationclick event?.

```js
 messaging()
    .send({
      notification: {
        title,
        body: message,
      },
      webpush: {
        notification: {
          icon:
            icon ??
            'https://storage.googleapis.com/mejora-continua-bucket/logoMejora.png',
        },
        fcmOptions: {
          // link: 'https://mejora-continua-dot-mx-vianney-001.uc.r.appspot.com/admin-usuarios',
          link: '/admin-usuarios',
        },
      },
      token: to,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

I receive the notification as this:

[Background notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBZee.png)

And my firebase sw is like this:

```js
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-app-compat.js"
);
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-messaging-compat.js"
);

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "myapikey",
  authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "myprojectid",
  storageBucket: "mystorage",
  messagingSenderId: "messageid",
  appId: "appid",
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log("Received background message ", payload);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tests, I found that the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` worker isn´t allowed to claim clients, I will try to register another service worker to manage the notifications to allow me to navigate the clients.

Edited:
I added a `client.postMessage(data)` to my serviceworker and then when focus the client in angular with a `fromEvent(navigator.serviceWorker, 'message')` Observable I receive de message and redirect with the Angular router. Hope this helps to anyone passing through the same problem.